# Do all apps that implement huawei iap need to have a .huawei sufix in the package name?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-iap

If an app integrates huawai iap, must it have a package name with a .huawei suffix in order for it to be accepted in AppGallery? (Assuming the app belongs in the App category - I know that apps in Game category must have a package name with a .huawei suffix)

Answer (score 0):

- Only games, that uses IAP Kit must have `.huawei` suffix in application ID.
- Games, that not use IAP Kit can be uploaded without `.huawei` suffix in application ID.
- Common applications (not games with IAP Kit) can be uploaded without suffix.

Answer (score 0):

For the package name used in Huawei App. Gallery, current requirements are as follows:

1. Do not include the word “**. huawei**” or “**.HUAWEI**” in app package name even if the app is
   integrated with Huawei IAP, it will be rejected by HAG (*Huawei App. Gallery*).
   Exception:  A game that uses Huawei IAP must include “**. huawei**” or “**.HUAWEI**” in
   app package name.
2. GMS APK: Use the same exact APK as the one from GPS (*Google Play Store*) to upload as GMS APK to HAG.
   This will ensure that both app stores will treat it as the same app in the event that a phone
   has both GPS and HAG installed.
3. HMS APK: Use a different package name and key signature to sign APKs for HAG. This will
   ensure that both app stores will not treat both APKs as the same and automatically
   overwriting each other. **WARNING: DO NOT use the same key signature and same
   package name on both app stores, doing so may break your user program data like
   In-app Purchases (IAP) history in Huawei legacy phones that have both GPS and HAG
   installed.**
4. When creating a different package name for HAG, please add suffix “**.ag**” to differentiate the
   APKs. For example: com.example.myapp.ag. **WARNING: Doing so will allow your user to
   install two APKs (two app icons) with the same app name in their phone, but is
   necessary to prevent GPS and HAG from overwriting each other.**
5. Do not change your package name after confirming with Huawei the name you plan to have.
   The package name is directly linked to the Huawei incentive agreement.

Answer (score 0):

> If an app integrates huawai iap, must it have a package name with a .huawei suffix in order for it to be accepted in AppGallery?

Please confirm your app category to be released first:

1. For common apps, **.huawei** is not mandatory.
2. For game apps, **.huawei** is mandatory.

In the scenario where the package name of a game app is forcibly changed, you are advised to use multiple channel packaging. Add the **.huawei** suffix to the package name in Huawei channel. Change the package name in **productFlavor** in the **build.gradle** file under the app directory.

```
flavorDimensions "flavor"
productFlavors{
    huawei {
        applicationId "com.huawei"
        dimension "flavor"
    }
    appMarket2{
        applicationId "com.appMarket2"
        dimension "flavor"
    }
}
```

For details about multi-channel packaging, please refer to [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-config-flavor#h1-1581245784585).

Comment: so if its a common app with HMS in app implemented, the package name can be without a .huawei suffix correct? I only ask again because in the developer console it says this: https://i.ibb.co/ZHKcCdW/Screenshot-2.png

Comment: yes@anja.For game apps, **.huawei** is mandatory.If its a common app,**.huawei** is not mandatory.